# Where is the function 'real_ugettext' in django?

Tags: python, django

In [`django.utils.translations.__init__.py`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/translation/__init__.py?rev=6582):

```
def ugettext(message):
    return real_ugettext(message)
```

I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [that file](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/translation/__init__.py?rev=6582) a little closer:

```
def delayed_loader(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Replace each real_* function with the corresponding function from either
    trans_real or trans_null (e.g. real_gettext is replaced with
    trans_real.gettext or trans_null.gettext). This function is run once, the
    first time any i18n method is called. It replaces all the i18n methods at
    once at that time.
    """
    #...
```

Answer (score 0):

Django does some nasty global-munging magic in order to replace it with ugettext from either trans_real or trans_null found in the same package.